# Where to find out what's changed in nvidia since 384.130?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

Here's the top of my system setup as reported by conky system monitor:

[image: conky nvidia.png]

- Kernel version 4.14.153, will be 4.14.168 when I get around to rebooting
- Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS triple booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04
- nVidia GeForce GTX 970M
- nVidia driver version 384.130

I'm extremely happy with my current setup but I'm wondering if there are new driver speed improvements or bug fixes for my GPU card.

I also use Intel HD 520 Skylake Thunderbolt III to HDMI convert for my other TV and it's working perfectly too.

Where can I read about nVidia driver improvements (e.g. speed) for Ubuntu/Linux considering my current setup?

My motto is "If it ain't broke don't fix it" so I like to do a lot of reading before upgrading. Software development is a hobby so bugs are a way of life, I just don't want external bugs. If a newer driver introduces bugs or has "software bloat" there isn't much point in upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the release notes for all Nvidia drivers [HERE](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us)

Just enter your info in the drop down menus and search, it will return all Nvidia drivers still in service.  If you select the driver version it will bring up a new page and give you 3 tabs.  The first will tell you what has changed since the last release. The second tab will give you a list of supported GPUs. The Third will give you additional information

If you want a lot of reading, you can go to the third tab and click on the **READ ME** at the bottom of the tab.  If will give you 40 pages of information about the release.

Comment: Thank you. I've upvoted your answer but besides the Library of Congress is there a way to narrow it down to to GTX 970M? I assume all the drivers since `384.130` support GTX 970M.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Not sure what you are asking here.  If you use the dropboxes: Product type-> Geforce /  Product Series-> Geforce 900M / Product-> GTX 970M, then enter you arch (32 or 64) it will only give you current drivers for the 970M.  You can go from there as check the drivers.  If you asking can you see only the changes specific to the 970M:  not as far as I can tell.  Nvidia's site for Linux leaves a bit to be desired.